# CentOS Development Tools "No package kernel-devel available."

Tags: kernel

When attempting to install the Development Tools on CentOS 7 I get the error:

```
Error: Package: systemtap-devel-2.8-10.el7.armv7hl (base)
           Requires: kernel-devel
```

However I can not seem to find a kernel-devel with yum search? Anyone know how to get around this issue?

Comment: http://www.spinics.net/lists/centos-arm-devel/msg01006.html

Answer (score 1):

Like [Sinclair](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/32619/sinclair) says, here is the [Repo](http://mirror.centos.org/altarch/7/kernel/armhfp/kernel-rpi2/Packages/) for Raspberry Pi 2/3. 
I suggest better than use the yum repo, download manually the rmp from it and install it using yum.

Answer (score 0):

Check that kernel files are not excluded from updates in the /etc/yum.conf file. If you see a line like this:

```
exclude=kernel*
```

comment it out and try the yum command again. You may need to run

```
yum clean all
```

first to re-populate the yum cache.

Answer (score -1):

CentOS 7 includes a kernel-devel package, see http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/.  Each update changes the kernel version (the 327 in kernel-devel-3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64.rpm).  The hardware architecture "x86_64" is also important.  Compare output from Linux command "uname -a" (reports information about your system) with the package name.

Yum only works if the repositories are configured and reachable.  Rpm files can also be located on a CentOS install DVD under the Packages directory.  You can install them with the "rpm -i" command.  Again, architecture and versions need to match.

Comment: This is not really relevant since the Pi does not use the x86_64 package but a custom arm build.